# Unable to log in to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Folks,
I am unable to log to a remote MySQL server using phpMyAdmin. Here is the error

`[Wed Mar 01 12:33:24 2017] [error] [client 'remoserverIP'] client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/`

When I try to log in directly in the MySQL server using remote server's CLI, I am able to log in without any problem. Other users are able to log in using phpMyAdmin. What am I doing wrong?

FYI, I do not have root/sudo access to change and restart anything.

Comment: sometime it can cause because of case sensitive can you tell what url you are accessing like [domain]/phpMyAdmin ?

Comment: Error is pretty clear. Check your configuration.

Comment: Any hints in your webserver error log?

Comment: Folks it was a firewall issue and since resolved.